# Variable assignment in conditional statement

Tags: c, while-loop

I have a code:

```
while (i = j) {
  /* not important */
}
```

For how long will this `while` loop work? Is it till the moment when the value of variable j is equal to zero?

Comment: Every sane compiler will warn about such an expression as condition. Because it is a commone error to foget the second `=` for `==`. It is also bad practice. Wrap into an explicit comparison or move the assignment out of the condition (which requires `break` inside the loop).

Comment: And that is an **assignment**, not an initialisation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `while` loop properties, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.8.5/p4, (*emphasis mine*)

> An iteration statement causes a statement called the loop body to be executed repeatedly
>   **until the controlling expression compares equal to 0.** [...]

and considering the *assignment* inside the loop condition, quoting §6.5.16/p3

> [...] An
>   assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment,<sup>111)</sup> but is not
>   an lvalue. [...]

So, every time the loop condition is executed, first the current value of `j` will be assigned to `i` and then, the value of `i` will be taken as the *controlling expression* value.

In other words, the loop will continue until `j` becomes `0`.

That said, **iff** you are sure about the assignment part as the loop condition statement, put it into double parenthesis like

```
 while ((i = j)){
```

Less confusion for the compiler and the next developer/maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

> For how long will this while loop work? Is it till the moment when the value of variable j is equal to zero?

- A `while` loop would would work till it's the `condition` or `expression` evaluates to be *false* (i.e, `0`).
- In your code, **YES** `while` loop works till the moment when the value of variable `j` is equal to `0`.

> **Note** : The assignment operator in C returns the value of the variable that was assigned i.e, the value of the expression `i = j` os equal to `j`.

- In `while(i = j)` , first `i` is assigned with value of `j`and then the expression is evaluated whether *true* or *false*.

---

- *Why not try a simple program :)* :

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void) 
  {
      int i = 0,j =10;
      while (i = j) 
      {
          printf("in loop when j = %d\n",j);
          j--;
      }
      printf("exited loop when j = %d",j);
  }
  ```
- **output :**

  ```
  in loop when j = 10
  in loop when j = 9
  in loop when j = 8
  in loop when j = 7
  in loop when j = 6
  in loop when j = 5
  in loop when j = 4
  in loop when j = 3
  in loop when j = 2
  in loop when j = 1
  exited loop when j = 0
  ```

Answer (score 0):

An assignment operation always returns the result of the assignment, so the loop will continue until `j == 0`, this behavior exists so you can chain many assignment operations together like so:

```
a = b = c;
```